# Setting logging scope globally in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-extensions-logging

I want to get certain key bits of information (service-name, service-version, host-name, etc) logged on every log message in an ASP.Net Core service.

I have the following code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        using (host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>().BeginScope("ServiceName: {0}", "bob-service"))
        {
            host.Run();
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(builder =>
            {
                builder.AddConsole(o => o.IncludeScopes = true);
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

From this I get the following logging:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      => ServiceName: bob-service
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5002

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker[102]
      => ConnectionId:0HLSO8706NGBN => RequestPath:/ RequestId:0HLSO8706NGBN:00000001, SpanId:|aa5794ba-408ad22a63064421., TraceId:aa5794ba-408ad22a63064421, ParentId: => Middleware_Scope => /Index
      Executed handler method OnGet, returned result .
```

Note how the `ServiceName` only appears on the host-level logging. The request-level logging does *not* include it.

Is there a mechanism for setting scope on *every* log-message that comes out of ASP.Net Core.

I've tried adding a piece of middleware to do this, and it mostly works, but the logging doesn't appear on the `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics"` log messages (although it appears on everything else as far as I can tell).

```
app
    .Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        // Middleware to add scoped values to log messages.
        var logger = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Startup>>();
        using (logger.BeginScope("ServiceName: {0}", "bob-service")))
        {
            await next();
        }
    });
```

### EDIT

Even when using the middleware described above, log messages from the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics` logger do not contain the scoped fields. For example, note how in the second log message, the `Middleware_Scope` scoped message does not appear.

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[6]
      => ConnectionId:0HLSOTDVELPJA => RequestPath:/css/site.css RequestId:0HLSOTDVELPJA:00000001, SpanId:|2fbd556d-44cc7c919266ccaf., TraceId:2fbd556d-44cc7c919266ccaf, ParentId: => Middleware_Scope
      The file /css/site.css was not modified

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      => ConnectionId:0HLSOTDVELPJD => RequestPath:/js/site.js RequestId:0HLSOTDVELPJD:00000001, SpanId:|2fbd5570-44cc7c919266ccaf., TraceId:2fbd5570-44cc7c919266ccaf, ParentId:
      Request finished in 29.8413ms 304 application/javascript
```

Comment: "but the logging doesn't appear on the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics" log messages" -- Isn't that covered from the first bit of code?

Comment: @chrispratt not in my testing sadly.

Comment: `logging doesn't appear on the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics" log messages` Do you mean when the log is produced by `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics`, the message defined in BeginScope did not shows up? Can you paste the logs contain the good case and bad case?

Comment: @Rena Please see my edit, containing the log message where it is missing.

Comment: Could you share what is the version of asp.net core?

Comment: @Rena ASP.Net Core 3.0.

Comment: `Microservice.GetBaseLoggingFields(Constants.Application.ServiceName)` What's the `Microservice.GetBaseLoggingFields` method here? Is it customer own method? and what's `Constants.Application.ServiceName`? is it also custom defined?

Comment: @Rena Those are just a copy-paste from the real application. I've removed them now, as the above is intended to be an MVCE.

Comment: @RB. did you figure out a way of doing global scope, I am also looking for options of doing something similar

Comment: Did you try changing logging to Trace? You can also get those values manually from your context request object in .NET and manually log the values you need that way. I would roll your own log class to capture those on every request and log them as information log levels.

Comment: If someone uses serilog, consider to use LogContext as described in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57460579/how-do-i-get-a-serilog-enricher-to-work-with-dependency-injection-while-keeping/57488163#comment115865101_57488163

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is right, but I came to set scopes globally using `ILoggerProvider` instead of `ILogger<T>`, and setting my own scope provider for it, something like this:

```cs
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        
        // ... other logging configurations, like ClearProviders() and AddJsonConsole(o => o.IncludeScopes = true);

        var provider = host.Services.GetService<ILoggerProvider>()
        if (provider is ISupportExternalScope scopedProvider)
        {
            var scopes = new LoggerExternalScopeProvider();
            scopes.Push("ServiceName: bob-service");
            scopedProvider.SetScopeProvider(scopes);
        }

        host.Run();
    }
```

You may have to use `GetServices<ILoggerProvider>` and take care of a list if you have more than one provider.