# Add Fields to Every ILogger<T> Call (Without Serilog or NLog)

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, ilogger

So I'm trying to log out some additional information to every, single logging call. Basically stuff like the environment and machine names.

I've got my logging set up like this:

```cs
        builder.Logging.AddJsonConsole(b =>
                                       {
                                           b.IncludeScopes   = true;
                                           b.TimestampFormat = "[dd-MM-yy -- HH:mm:ss]";
                                       });
```

And I set up a bit of middleware that I thought would do the trick:

```cs
        app.Use(async (c, n) => 
        {
            var logger = c.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            using (logger.BeginScope("{EnvironmentName}", "myEnvironment"))
            {
                await n();
            }
        });
```

However, this doesn't actually seem to be appending the new field to all of my logs - it comes up on manual calls to `Logger.LogX()` but not anything generated by `Hosting.Diagnostics`:

```json
{
  "Timestamp": "[18-01-22 -- 10:42:41]",
  "EventId": 2,
  "LogLevel": "Information",
  "Category": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics",
  "Message": "Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:29965/ - - - 404 0 - 462.7596ms",
  "State": {
    "Message": "Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:29965/ - - - 404 0 - 462.7596ms",
    "ElapsedMilliseconds": 462.7596,
    "StatusCode": 404,
    "ContentType": null,
    "ContentLength": 0,
    "Protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "Method": "GET",
    "Scheme": "http",
    "Host": "localhost:29965",
    "PathBase": "",
    "Path": "/",
    "QueryString": ""
  },
  "Scopes": [
    {
      "Message": "SpanId:d592c9c95a00b532, TraceId:9a3c107a9f7d5a5422692f5bdaf6cf56, ParentId:0000000000000000",
      "SpanId": "d592c9c95a00b532",
      "TraceId": "9a3c107a9f7d5a5422692f5bdaf6cf56",
      "ParentId": "0000000000000000"
    },
    {
      "Message": "ConnectionId:0HMEQDT08VU1Q",
      "ConnectionId": "0HMEQDT08VU1Q"
    },
    {
      "Message": "RequestPath:/ RequestId:0HMEQDT08VU1Q:00000002",
      "RequestId": "0HMEQDT08VU1Q:00000002",
      "RequestPath": "/"
    }
  ]
}
```

```json
{
  "Timestamp": "[18-01-22 -- 10:57:27]",
  "EventId": 1,
  "LogLevel": "Information",
  "Category": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware",
  "Message": "Executed endpoint 'HTTP: GET subscriptioninfo/api/alive-test'",
  "State": {
    "Message": "Executed endpoint 'HTTP: GET subscriptioninfo/api/alive-test'",
    "EndpointName": "HTTP: GET subscriptioninfo/api/alive-test",
    "{OriginalFormat}": "Executed endpoint '{EndpointName}'"
  },
  "Scopes": [
    {
      "Message": "SpanId:8aa7c06a93c883d6, TraceId:efc7d6f4907471d88077e7b4eaba4295, ParentId:0000000000000000",
      "SpanId": "8aa7c06a93c883d6",
      "TraceId": "efc7d6f4907471d88077e7b4eaba4295",
      "ParentId": "0000000000000000"
    },
    {
      "Message": "ConnectionId:0HMEQE57CSO2D",
      "ConnectionId": "0HMEQE57CSO2D"
    },
    {
      "Message": "RequestPath:/subscriptioninfo/api/alive-test RequestId:0HMEQE57CSO2D:00000002",
      "RequestId": "0HMEQE57CSO2D:00000002",
      "RequestPath": "/subscriptioninfo/api/alive-test"
    },
    {
      "Message": "myEnvironment",
      "EnvironmentName": "myEnvironment",
      "{OriginalFormat}": "{EnvironmentName}"
    }
  ]
}
```

I feel like adding some default fields to a request should be easy. It's easy to do with Serilog and NLog. So how do I achieve this without using a separate logging framework?

Comment: did you find a way to do this or were you forced to fall back to to NLog/Serilog?

Comment: Had to fall back to Serilog

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object>{ ["Env"] = env})
```

Comment: Yeah, this has the same problem, I've editted my question with some clarifiaction

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59720429/14202100

Comment: Aye I've seen it, it's not got an aswer though