# Serilog DI in ASP.NET Core, which ILogger interface to inject?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, serilog

**Context**

I've successfully configured Serilog in my ASP.NET Core application, only the DI part remains.

**Question**

Now I have two ILogger interfaces, one is `Serilog.ILogger` the other is `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`. Both works based on my Serilog config, and I do not know which to use? (I mean, after Serilog config in place `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger` also correctly logging through Serilog, so my config is honored)

In case `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger` I do know how to configure DI to make it work.
However in case of `Serilog.ILogger` I see that Serilog has a static Log.Logger instance (probably a singleton)

I do not want to use this static property in my code, mainly for testing reasons, so I would like to to constructor inject it. The solution would be:

```
services.AddSingleton(Log.Logger); // Log.Logger is a singleton anyway
```

..but I am concerning about this singleton in a Web Application when many multiple threads will use this very same instance concurrently. Is it thread safe? If it is not, then what would be the solution to use `Serilog.ILogger` with DI?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Choosing which interface to use **within your application** is a matter of taste, really. If you prefer Serilog's `ILogger` shorter method names (e.g. `log.Error` vs `log.LogError`), go with that, otherwise use the Microsoft's generic `ILogger<>`. You have control over all the dependencies you use in your own projects, so there's no strong technical reason to prefer one over the other.

You might be interested in reading this issue on Serilog's repo:

> [Should I use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger or Serilog.ILogger?](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/issues/104).

I personally use Serilog's `ILogger` across all my projects not only because I do prefer the shorter method names, but also because I prefer *not* to inject a logger in every single constructor of every class, and it's also easy to have a [contextual logger for every class](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Writing-Log-Events#source-contexts) using `Log.ForContext<>`, which is useful when troubleshooting issues. E.g.

```
public class SomeService
{
    private readonly ILogger _log = Log.ForContext<SomeService>();
    // ...
}

public class SomeRepository
{
    private readonly ILogger _log = Log.ForContext<SomeRepository>();
    // ...
}
```

---

**If you were developing a library** though, I'd recommend using Microsoft's generic `ILogger<>`, of course, instead of taking a dependency on `Serilog` and force consumers of your library to also take a dependency on `Serilog`.

---

`Log.Logger` is thread-safe, thus registering as a singleton as you are doing above is correct if you want all classes to share the same instance ([without `SourceContext`s](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Writing-Log-Events#source-contexts)) - nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Thx, but what about unit testing? Hardcoding that Log.ForContext requires that unit test must deal with a real Serilog logger instead of mocking, and use for example the mock to assert logging functionality.

Comment: @g.pickardou Not really... _It Just Works (tm)_... By default, `Log.Logger` points to a `SilentLogger` which does a [no-op](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)) so you don't have to do anything special for your unit tests to work...

Comment: @g.pickardou Of course, if you want to test for specific log outputs, then you just have to create a mock implementation of Serilog's `ILogger` and change `Log.Logger` to point to the mock, in your tests...

Answer (score 5):

You should setup logging in your `Program.cs` file as part of the `Host` setup as described in the documentation (https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Getting-Started).

You should not manually add anything to your `ServiceCollection` as you show above.

For DI, you should inject the Microsoft generic `ILogger<>` as described in the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/#create-logs). This `ILogger<>` instance will automatically log to *all* the providers you have configured (this could include Serilog but also any additional loggers configured such as file, console, etc.).