# Use Serilog with Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, serilog, ilogger

I've created a .NET Core 3.1 project using a Host, the IoC container with `IServiceCollection` and implemented logging allover the place using the `ILogger<T>` interface from `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`. I now need to implement more advanced logging and decided to use Serilog.

I assumed that it would be a breeze to switch from .NET built-in loggers to Serilog. But to my surprise, Serilog is using it's own `ILogger` interface - bummer! So now I needed to update ALL places to use Serilog `ILogger`, or to implement Serilog with a .NET Core `ILogger<T>` interface.

My question is - is it really not possible to use Serilog with the ILogger interface in `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`? Would be so much smarter!

Comment: "_I kinda assumed that it would be a breeze to switch from .NET built-in loggers to Serilog_" - It is... Just use [Serilog's provider for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging)

Comment: Also, you might be interested in this other question: "[Serilog DI in ASP.NET Core, which ILogger interface to inject?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61411759/211672)"

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In the `Serilog.Extensions.Logging` assembly there is a extension method on `IloggingBuilder` called `AddSerilog` (it's in the Serilog namespace) that will allow you to use Serilog for logging. For example:

**.NET Core 2.2 and earlier (using `WebHost`):**

```cs
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.AddSerilog();
    });
```

**.NET Core 3.1 and later (using generic `Host` for either web or console apps):**

```cs
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()})
    .UseSerilog();
```

Now the `ILogger` and `ILogger<>` implementation will call into Serilog.

Comment: And if you're using Generic Host, there is Serilog.Extensions.Hosting package which has a UseSerilog method to configure the Serilog setup

Answer (score 30):

**For .NET 6 and later**

```cs
using Serilog;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration));
```

Reference: [Here](https://blog.datalust.co/using-serilog-in-net-6/)

Comment: You'll need to run `dotnet add package Serilog.AspNetCore` for ASP.NET Core or `Serilog.Extensions.Hosting` before referencing those lines.

Comment: @Exegesis When would I want to use `Serilog.Extensions.Hosting` instead of `Serilog.AspNetCore`?

Comment: @MassDotNet You'll use `Hosting` for console applications.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to ways by using `builder.host.UseSeriLog()` extensions method.
Here is more elegant way *(we can use in external console or unit test ILogger without implementation of main project)*.

1. Install Nuget Package `Serilog.Extensions.Logging` along with core package `Serilog`.
2. Initialize Logger Configuration like you already doing. For example a typical logging configuration would be write to Console would be like `Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration).WriteTo.Console().CreateLogger()`.
3. Use `ILoggerFactory` extension method `AddSeriLog()` like this `ILoggerFactory factory = new LoggerFactory().AddSerilog(Log.Logger);`
4. Simply return `factory.CreateLogger<T>();`

```cs
public static Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger LoggingInstance<T>()
{
  Serilog.Log.Logger = Serilog.Log.Logger ?? new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.(xxxxYourSinksxxxx).CreateLogger();
  ILoggerFactory factory = new LoggerFactory().AddSerilog(Log.Logger);            
  return factory.CreateLogger<T>();
}
```

Its usage be like

`var logger = LoggingInstance<YourModel>();`

Answer (score 0):

You can register Serilog to handle `ILogger<T>` in your constructors from DI with the following:

Add the Nuget package `Serilog.Extensions.Logging` and then register with:

```
services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
    loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(dispose: true));
```

Now when your class is instantiated and requests an `ILogger<ClassName> logger` in the constructor it'll be provided with a Serilog logger.

Answer (score -2):

I had a need for logging in a very simple console app (.NET6) and started wondering what the absolute minimal Serilog implementation would look like. Contrary to many SO questions about this, Serilog is not "heavyweight" by any means. The total DLL size for this is smaller than the MS Logging extensions (since the extensions pull in stuff like DI that isn't needed here).

Packages:

- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging v6.0.0
- Serilog v3.0.1
- Serilog.Extensions.Logging v3.1.0
- Serilog.Sinks.Async v1.5.0
- Serilog.Sinks.Console v4.1.0
- Serilog.Sinks.File v5.0.0

Console program:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var iLogger = GetILogger("ConsoleProgram", "./test.log");

    // uses MS ILogger to write to console and file
    iLogger.LogInformation("this is a test"); 

    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}

static ILogger GetILogger(string categoryName, string pathname)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .WriteTo.Async(a => a.File(pathname))
        .CreateLogger();

    return new SerilogLoggerFactory()
        .CreateLogger(categoryName);
}
```

Of course, you could break up the fluent config to make the console output optional, or store the factory reference if you have multiple categories, etc, but the point is you don't need all that DI Service, Configuration, Hosting, or Builder overhead.

Comment: The question was how to setup Serilog so it integrates with Microsoft IOC container and specifically the ILogger interface from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.

Comment: Yes and it already had an accepted answer, so what's your point? I clearly stated the purpose of my post. I don't care about the downvote or points, but for your edification: it's common on SO to add additional useful context, particularly after long periods of time.