# Populate custom columns in Serilog MsSql sink

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I am using Serilog in my dotnet core application. I have added custom columns to the default list of columns provided by Serilog. Below is how my "Serilog" configuration looks like in appsettings.json file -

```
"Serilog": {
"MinimumLevel": "Information",
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "MSSqlServer",
    "Args": {
      "connectionString": <connectionString>
      "tableName": "Log",
      "autoCreateSqlTable": true,
      "columnOptionsSection": {
        "removeStandardColumns": [ "MessageTemplate", "Properties"], //remove the Properties column in the standard ones
        "customColumns": [
          {
            "ColumnName": "ControllerName",
            "DataType": "varchar",
            "DataLength": 50
          }
        ]
      },
      "timeStamp": {
        "columnName": "Timestamp",
        "convertToUtc": true
      }
    }
    }
]
}
```

So I have removed "MessageTemplate" and "Properties" from the default list of columns created by Serilog and added **"ControllerName"** as a new column to the table **Log**, where Serilog logs its data. What i want is that when I am logging information , I want to provide value to the "ControllerName" column. How can it be done?
I have found the below solution :

```
_logger.LogInformation("{ControllerName}{Message}", "TestController", "Starting up..");
```

This line of code provides value to the ControllerName column, but the message column gets the value as

```
"TestController""Starting up.."
```

I want the message column to get value as

```
 Starting up..
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto : "ControllerName" is just an example and part of a POC. Actually i want to use one or more custom columns and provide them values when i am logging. Columns like - Service Name etc.

Comment: You may use `IDiagnosticContext` interface to set an additional properties. [Logging the selected Endpoint Name with Serilog](https://andrewlock.net/using-serilog-aspnetcore-in-asp-net-core-3-logging-the-selected-endpoint-name-with-serilog/) can be used as starting point here

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski - I found this to be useful - https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment                          i want to know using LogContext.PushProperty() is fine ? Any performance issues ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you are using Microsoft's `ILogger<T>` instead of Serilog's `ILogger` thus in order to add a contextual property that will be included in your log event without being part of the message, you have to create a new [logging scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#log-scopes) using `BeginScope` e.g.

```
using (_logger.BeginScope("{ControllerName}", nameof(TestController)))
{
    _logger.LogInformation("{Message}", "Starting up..."); 
}
```

Another alternative is to add a property to Serilog's `LogContext`:

```
using (LogContext.PushProperty("ControllerName", nameof(TestController))
{
    _logger.LogInformation("{Message}", "Starting up..."); 
}
```

This will give you the same end result as with `BeginScope` above, but is a Serilog-specific API and kind of defeats the purpose of using `ILogger<T>` in the first place, so `BeginScope` would be preferred unless you decide to use Serilog's `ILogger` instead.

One important observation is that in order for the `LogContext` to work, you need to enable it when you configure your logger. For example:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext() // <<<<<<<<<<#############
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();
```

If you were to use Serilog's `ILogger`, then in addition to be able to use the `LogContext` you can alternatively create a new context using `Log.ForContext`:

```
var contextLogger = logger.ForContext("ControllerName", nameof(TestController));
contextLogger.Information("{Message}", "Starting up...");
```

---

ps: If you're not sure whether you should use Microsoft's `ILogger<T>` or Serilog's `ILogger`, I recommend reading this answer: [Serilog DI in ASP.NET Core, which ILogger interface to inject?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61413261/211672)