# Serilog has no method ".ForContext ()"

Tags: logging, serilog, .net-core-2.1

In my project, logging is implemented using Serilog. When I try to log a line, I would like to add some values that should not be included in the message, but should be in the log.

My _Logger doesn't have a ".ForContext" () method for this.
Maybe I'm wrong registered serilog?

Handler class:

```
public class LogHandler 
    {
        private readonly ILogger<LogHandler> _logger;

        public LogHandler(ILogger<LogHandler> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

       **_logger.(HAS NO METHOD)ForContext("Hello", ...);** 
}
```

Program.cs:

```
namespace LoggingExample
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureLogging(loggingConfiguration => loggingConfiguration.ClearProviders())
            .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
                loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext());
    }
```

}

Startup:

```
namespace LoggingExample
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<ILogHandler, LogHandler>()
                .AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Settings:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Graylog", "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Override": {
        "LoggingExample.Handler": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Graylog",
        "Args": {
          "hostnameOrAddress": "127.0.0.1",
          "port": "1514",
          "transportType": "Tcp"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext",
      "WithMachineName"
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "Centralized logging application"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: `ILogger<>` is from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging and you need to use its scoping stuff if you want to do that. Or, you can skip using those and use Serilog's ILogger only (Serilog does not do the generics to denote the context out of the box as far as I'm aware)

Comment: Thank you. It is good advice for me. I will use **"private readonly Serilog.ILogger _logger;"**
instead **"private readonly ILogger<LogHandler> _logger;"**

Comment: @nether201 Note that Microsoft's ILogger<T> also supports contexts through `BeginScope`. You might be interested in reading [Serilog DI in ASP.NET Core, which ILogger interface to inject?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61413261)